# Setting background image in a custom view

Tags: android, view, background-image

I have created a class which extends View class.

```
public class SplashScreen extends View
```

and i use it by setting contentview

```
View splash = new SplashScreen(this);
setContentView(splash);
```

I need to set background image but I can't use layout. I think I need to do canvas drawing but I don't know how to do.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  ballBounds.set(ballX-ballRadius, ballY-ballRadius, ballX+ballRadius, ballY+ballRadius);
  paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
  // canvas.drawImage(R.drawable.background_image); (Ps: I know there is no function such as drawImage)"
  canvas.drawOval(ballBounds, paint);}
```

Comment: Why can't you use layout? IF you use LayoutInflator you can.

Comment: I mean I can't use layout xml. I don't have a xml file for this view. and I can't use 
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

Comment: Related post - [Full screen background image in an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16135984/465053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to just set the background you can do

```
public SplashScreen(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add image on canvas as:

```
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic180);  
        Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(0.8f, 0.8f);
        matrix.postRotate(45);
        Bitmap dstbmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,0,0,bmp.getWidth(),
        bmp.getHeight(),matrix,true);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK); 
        canvas.drawBitmap(dstbmp, 10, 10, null);
```

Comment: thanks that was what I'm looking for but it slows the app like hell! I need to figure out new way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for, and it works like a charm. @Srht, you should load the image once, especially if you have this code in OnDraw()

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want to change `SplachScreen` type to `activity`? Then `setContentView` change to whatever your `layout` is and if you want that splach screen appear before your application, make it first in `Manifest` and in `splashscreen` end, destroy `activity` and start your application menu activity. Then you won't need View class and less work finding where is problem

Comment: Do I make canvas drawings without using view class? (Maybe a silly question but I really don't know)