# Change background of a custom view when touched

Tags: android, view

I want to change the background color of a customView when it's pressed and slightly "remove" this background color when the view losses the "pressed-state". However, I googled this question and found a solution using a StateListDrawable. I've tried this within my customView (which is added to a ListView programmatically), but just the "normal color" was set to my view. When I touched the view nothing happens. What's going wrong?

the selector xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/bckgr" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

within the constructor of my custom view:

```
this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_bckgr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply your `background` to the `View` the `Adapter` fills up (the view your `getView`  implementation is returning) not to the `ListView` self

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [`android:descendantFocusability`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3adescendantFocusability) to true on the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Are you making the view focussable and clickable, use in the constructor:

```
setClickable(true);
setFocusable(true);
```

May be your view isn't getting focus.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `OnTouchListener` to handle touch events. When the view is touched, change the background, and when the view is 'untouched', change the background back to the original.

To set the listener, call the View.setOnTouchListener() function of your custom view with the OnTouchListener you create to handle these events.

Here is the reference to OnTouchListener:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you have an override method to the `OnTouch()` method, what I would do is create an `instance variable` (class var) that would hold the image that you want to have as a background, and set it in your `OnTouch()` method. Then, Override your `OnDraw()` method which would give you a reference to the `canvas`, and use the `canvas.DrawBitmap()` to draw your background.

This answer shows you more details on how to draw the `bitmap`
[Setting background image in a custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115820/setting-background-image-in-a-custom-view/#11115894)