# Full screen background image in an activity

Tags: android, background, imageview, android-framelayout

I see many applications that use a full-screen image as background.
This is an example:

[image: Full screen background image]

I want to use this in a project, the best way I've found so far to do this is to use an image with a large size, put it in a `ImageView` and use `android: adjustViewBounds="true"` to adjust the margins

The problem is that if a screen with a very high resolution, the image falls short.

Another option I thought of is to use the image in a `FrameLayout`, with `match_parent` in `width` and `height` as background... this stretches the image, but I think the result is not very good.

How would you do it?

Comment: Don't believe this works on backgrounds, but it should work on images. `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: Related post - [Android splash screen image sizes to fit all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10574363/465053)

Answer (score 244, accepted):

There are several ways you can do it.

**Option 1:**

Create different perfect images for different dpi and place them in related drawable folder. Then set

`android:background="@drawable/your_image"`

**Option 2:**

Add a single large image. Use FrameLayout. As a first child add an `ImageView`. Set the following in your ImageView.

```
android:src="@drawable/your_image"
android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
```

Comment: where do you store 'your_image'?

Comment: In the res->drawable folders. There may be multiple - each stand for a different resolution (ex. low resolution/high resolution). If you don't have specific images for each resolution, any one will work.

Comment: The answer is good. But i wonder if someone found the typical phone sizes for each dpi group, which would be quite useful when preparing images. Edited: found - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices/15744389#15744389

Comment: last option -> out of memory :D

Comment: Wouldn't mixing option 1 and 2 be the best option?

Comment: OOM error here we come...if its a large image your going to need to scale up or down depending on screen size! in this case you will need to most likely load a bitmap via asynchronous task.

Comment: Best option is option #2. Use an image of 600x730 (width is important), scales very well on different devices. If you can use png's, use it and optimize it with tinypng.com. The image I made has a black background so use black as blackground color. You can use this 'trick' with any color ofcourse.

Comment: Forgot to mention: Don't use scaling! It can be very ugly when the image is upscaling (beter is downscaling). Use android:layout_gravity="center" instead of android:scaleType = "centerCrop" (<- this cause upscaling and image doesn't look that pretty and aligned).

Comment: Should we put the images in the different mitmap folders for option 2? Because mitmap isn't drawable

Comment: which one is better?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 3.4, android:src="@drawable/your_image"  is not working in my case so I'm using android:background="@drawable/your_image" instead.

Answer (score 26):

Another option is to add a single image (not necessarily big) in the drawables (let's name it backgroung.jpg), create an ImageView iv_background at the root of your xml without a "src" attribute.
Then in the onCreate method of the corresponding activity:

```
    /* create a full screen window */
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

    /* adapt the image to the size of the display */
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
      getResources(),R.drawable.background),size.x,size.y,true);

    /* fill the background ImageView with the resized image */
    ImageView iv_background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_background);
    iv_background.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

No cropping, no many different sized images.
Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a useful solution, but remember to do bitmap processing off of the main thread: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Answer (score 19):

You should put the various size images into the followings folder

for more detail visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing)

- ldpi
- mdpi
- hdpi
- xhdpi
- xxhdpi

and use RelativeLayout or LinearLayout background instead of using ImageView as follwoing example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/your_image">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that `Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag RelativeLayout`

Comment: This makes my Fragment so laggy. Can't figure out why.

Comment: use cache or load image with picasso( http://square.github.io/picasso/) hope will solve your problem

Answer (score 9):

It's been a while since this was posted, but this helped me.

You can use nested layouts. Start with a RelativeLayout, and place your ImageView in that.

Set height and width to match_parent to fill the screen.

Set scaleType="centreCrop" so the image fits the screen and doesn't stretch.

Then you can put in any other layouts as you normally would, like the LinearLayout below.

You can use android:alpha to set the transparency of the image.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:alpha="0.6"/>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"/>

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="There"/>

   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

What about

`android:background="@drawable/your_image"`

on the main layout of your activity?

This way you can also have different images for different screen densities by placing them in the appropriate `res/drawable-**dpi` folders.

Answer (score 7):

use this

```
android:background="@drawable/your_image"
```

in your activity very first linear or relative layout.

Answer (score 7):

If you want your image to show BEHIND a transparent Action Bar, put the following into your Theme's style definition:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

In lines with the answer of NoToast, you would need to have multiple versions of "your_image" in your res/drawable-ldpi,mdpi, hdpi, x-hdpi (for xtra large screens), **remove match_parent** and keep **android: adjustViewBounds="true"**

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:background="@drawable/your_image"` inside your Relativelayout/Linearlayout
Worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bg.png as your background image then simply:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Working. you should tryout this:

```
android:src="@drawable/img"
```

Answer (score -1):

**`three step for put background`**

1)you should choose your like picture. for example :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3jVn.jpg)

2)Then you copy this picture in drawable.
    warning: you should choose types short for name picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzKAC.jpg)

3)you go to page xml Intended and write :

android:background="id picture"
for example my picture id is @drawable/download.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF38Q.jpg)

finish.

Answer (score -2):

**The easiest way:**

Step 1: Open AndroidManifest.xml file

[You can see the file here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFXfa.png)

Step 2: Locate `android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`

Step 3: Change to `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >`

Step 4: Then Add ImageView & Image

Step 4: That's it!