# How do I get background resource to fill LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-drawable

Here is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backg"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AppleActivity" >
...
<LinearLayout>
```

I expect the background to fill the layout. But it leaves considerable space based on top and at the bottom. I don't mind if the background stretches. I just want it to fill the view. Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

In case it's important: in my manifest file I am using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"` to hide the status bar.

Comment: upload one snap please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135984/full-screen-background-image-in-an-activity/16139059#16139059

Comment: @learner can you remove the padding and check?

Comment: remove the android:padding property

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but removing the padding didn't work. The funny thing is I have never seen this before. I background always fills the view. I just don't see what it could be.

Comment: it should work. what happend if you remove padding? put some color code in place of @drawable/backg inorer to debug it. if all these things are not working. take a imageview with scaleXY and set height & width match_parent

Comment: May be the **backg** image has the transparent margins, better check the Image once !!

Comment: `@drawable/backg` refers to an image?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this..

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backg"
 android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

into your linear layout? This will stretch your background image to linear layout bounds. You can also use centerCrop to fit the image to bounds without stretching it.

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Also, use margin instead of padding.