# How to set the ScaleType on a LinearLayout's background image

Tags: android

I have a linear layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapp" >
```

What I need now is the possibility to set the background image `ScaleType` value in order to fill the screen everytime, this because I'm going to download the image and then I'm going to set it as background but without ScaleType the images will not keep it's aspect ratio based on the screen densities.

What I found is this solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bgapp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:gravity="bottom|left" />
```

But It doesn't work as expected.. Is there a way to set a `LinearLayout` `scaleType` property or do I need to change my layout?

Comment: you cannot use scaletype in linearlayout .. you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16139059/931982

Comment: @pskink can you explain how to use it?

Comment: @pskink I'll try it tomorrow and I'll let you know, thanks :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

View's background is stretched depending on the size of the `View`.

Image scaling is supported by `ImageView`, and to use it together with the `LinearLayout` you need an additional container, that will overlay the 2 children (e.g. a `FrameLayout`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/bgapp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    ...
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @pskink yes you may be right about the custom drawable. I was talking about how `View` background attribute works in general.

Comment: yeah I saw this type of solution too but I didn't want to change my xml structure just for a background image, I'm still hoping for a solution that allows LinearLayout to have the scaleType options. thanks anyways!

Comment: did you get any sollution? @Signo

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar lol I was just searching for one right now :D still nothing i'm sorry :( btw this is a correct solution, I just didn't want to change my xml

Comment: Not worked. I need use `ScalingFrameLayout` for my aim.

Comment: Using `ImageView` you'll satisfy accessibility. Imaging they have `TextView`s inside this `LinearLayout`. `ImageView` won't stretch to accommodate space for increased font