# Background image gets shrink on keyboard popup

Tags: android, image, scrollview, drawable, window-soft-input-mode

I have a parent layout with background image, so after adding scroll view when the keyboard pops up the background image gets shrink.

Like below images :

[image]

[image]

I checked all solutions on SO, adding windowSofInput as adjustResize and adjustPan but adjustResize dosent solve the problem and by using adjustPan cant scroll up the page, scroll view dosent work with adjust pan.

I tried adding some attributes of scroll view like fillViewPort, adjustViewBounds to true.

Also I tried the 
    true
With this scroll view dose not shrink but, I dont need the full screen, status bar cant be seen with full screen.

I tried to add the image view rather than setting the background image to the parent layout, and tried to set its scaleType, matrix scale type dosent shrink but my backgroung image dose not look like original image.

It looks like tihs :

[image]

[image]

layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.admin.SmartCabFuelCard.RegisterDriver">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/page"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/bg_color"
        android:alpha="0.5"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds = "true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.example.admin.SmartCabFuelCard.RegisterDriver"><!--

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/page"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
-->


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/petrolpump" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/register_driver_welcome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:text="@string/welcome_driver"
                android:textColor="@color/divider_color"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_mobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/register_driver_welcome"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_local_phone"
                android:hint="Mobile No."
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/divider_color"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/register_driver_enter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edt_mobile"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:text="@string/otp_send"
                android:textColor="@color/divider_color"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_driver_otp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/register_driver_enter"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_close"
                android:hint="OTP"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/divider_color"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_15dp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/register_driver_register"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/register_driver_otp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="Register"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/register_driver_sendotp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edt_mobile"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="Send OTP"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_resend"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/register_driver_register"
                android:layout_below="@+id/register_driver_otp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="RESEND OTP"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me with this please? Thank you.

Comment: Please post your layout xml

Comment: yes added please check @Naz141

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135984/full-screen-background-image-in-an-activity (using frame layout and add the image view first) .. also is there a reason why u nest your relative layout inside another relative layout (scroll view -> relative layout -> relative layout)?

Comment: yes,, but this not helping it still gets shrink. @JasonSaruulo

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the background in xml. Set the image as window background in your activity as.

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

And manifest entry

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Comment: This is working.. but some image hides below appbar as it is set to the window screen. @ADM

Comment: Yeah thats because its sets to window . If you are using AppBar then you can just use Linearlayout in xml as root  with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" in manifest. I sent this solution because the images you attached don't show any AppBar .

Comment: I cant use Linear layout, I have alredy set the view according to relative layout as parent. I tried to add adjustNothing to relative but did not work.

Comment: Your layout doesn't  seems complex its so simple . if putting  Linear layout solve issue so just add it as root parent layout .

Comment: ok I tried but it did not solve the issue, image is still behind the app bar.

Comment: Update your xml in question . cause don't see any AppBar  right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160176/discussion-between-sid-and-adm).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set a background image, you should set it on your parent relativelayout instead of using an imageview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/page"
tools:context="com.example.admin.SmartCabFuelCard.RegisterDriver">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_color"
    android:alpha="0.5"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds = "true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:fillViewport="true">

.....
```