# Image is not covering full background

Tags: xml, android-studio

I am building a chat application and when I send an image to the user, the image is not covering the background that I have given instead It is giving wired padding top and bottom. How to solve this issue. The padding that I have given is 7dp to each side
    here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageContentUser"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/doc"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]
I expect this to be the result.
[image]
But I am getting this as result

Comment: Why don't you [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135984/full-screen-background-image-in-an-activity) first. I came here by [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. You should not tag unnecessarily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full screen background image in an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135984/full-screen-background-image-in-an-activity)

Comment: you can google before post question...remove  android:src="@drawable/doc" and use  android:background="@drawable/doc" , android:scaleType="fitXY"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Scale type has many values like `matrix, fitXY, fitStart, fitCenter, firEnd, center, centerCrop, centerInside`

You use `fitXY`, It'll cover the all Screen if you choose it to `match_parent`or maybe your desired `length and width`

It should be like this finally :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_background_image" />
```

Hope this will work for you.