# Fill an image to full screen keeping the aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout

My question is the same as [Full screen background image in an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135984/full-screen-background-image-in-an-activity). I did not use the background option but use the `ImageView` option, because I want to keep the aspect ratio (I do not mind some parts of the image getting cropped). I think the solution worked before, but somehow it started not working and showing a white status bar instead.
[image]

I have tried other things in the question above, but I could not get the result I want (the background image below the status bar). What have I done wrong? Here are the entire source code that matters (I excluded the boilerplate.)

PS: I want to keep the status bar. What I want is like the screenshot of the linked question: full-screen image and a translucent status bar above the image. If I set the background image to the root layout, I get the result I want, except that the image aspect ratio is not kept. See the image below.

[image]

Manifest

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
```

Layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/doge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Style v21

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Style

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

---

[Added] I finally have got it working. But it was sort of weird. First, the root had to be CoordinatorLayout. ConstraintLayout did not work. Secondly, the must be a dummy view like below. If the dummy view was removed, the status bar became white. Whether `android:statusBarColor` or `android:windowTranslucentStatus` did not matter. The former made the status bar transparent, and the latter made it shady. See the screenshots, below. I think this may be a bug of the Support Library 27.1.0.

This layout worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/doge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar issue, the solution is to make `CoordinatorLayout` the root layout, and then inside of it add your former layout root.

Also, removing this part in Style v21 might help too:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: Yeah, it did require a CoordinatorLayout, and also a dummy view. Please take a look at the added part of my OP.